# Every rails application is creating 'somedatabase' for development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Whenever I am trying to create a new application in rails, it is generating correct database.yml file with the correct database name for development environment. But when I run command `rails / rake db:create`, it is creating database 'somedatabase' for development.

```
$ rake db:create
Created database 'somedatabase' 
Created database 'Todo-App_test'
```

I am running rails on Ubuntu 16.04. Even reinstalling rails/ruby didn't help me. Tried this on Rails 5.0 / 4.2.6 but same result. Tested with both mysql & sqlite3

Comment: How do you create new applications? How does the `config/database.yml` of such a new application look like?

Comment: This sounds like you might have set an environment variable somewhere.  Which program are you using to manage your Rubies?

Comment: @spickermann rails new App-Name

config/database.yml is as expected 

development:
  <<: *default
  database: App_Name_development

Comment: @Chris I am using rbenv

Comment: @SachinSrivastava so you got it working?

Comment: Thank you @Chris it was an environment related issue only, added DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase" in the /etc/environment

Comment: @SachinSrivastava you should answer your question, so that when future people visit this thread they will know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Chris My apologies & Thanks for reminding me. I am very much new to here so little unknown with all these. Anyways I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is look in the `config/database.yml` file to see if there's anything there. Then I would look at the `db/migrate` folder to see the contents of each file. Finally I would do a global search for `somedatabase` using your text editor. For example in Sublime Text you would click the menu item `File > Find in Files...`.

Comment: Thank you. It was environment related issue.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I had added this environment variable

> > DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"

in the **/etc/environment**

```
Resolved by removing this environment variable.
```